# Tensorflow : model.fit() first epoch takes a long initialize time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Thank you very much for reading my question. as described as in the title, since I cant quite seem to find a lot of people sharing elsewhere. may I please just ask here that what is the usual average period of time for a model to start `initialise` `model.fit()`

that is the wait time from `blank`   :
[image]

to the model really start fitting the `first step`  in the `first epoch`.

[image]

as Im learning into tensorflow building some minimally more complex model, the time I wait for it to start `fit()` is taking longer. I am not using any convulution layers, but have some recurrent `RNN` layers.

running `not` in `eager mode`, is there any trick or configuration that novice usually overlooks that actually could optimise the process ?

ie would I benefit from writting `custom trainning layer` `custom fit and backprog ?` which really arent too hard but I havent tried, I also googled and see people `building tensorflow from source` seeing some better performance. I can rule out the possibility of tensorflow retracing the functions, I experimented input_signature and dont see any improvement.

Im running tensorflow with `Ubuntu 20.04; tf.__version__ 2.5.0;`

what should be the usual wait time actually ? for medium size neural network maybe 10 layers and total parameters around 15 million. the trainning time `per epoch` once model is set up is fine.```

currently per epoch is ~9 mins but before first step `its preparation constructing graph I guess` takes about 1 hour and 10 minutes

Thank you very much

Comment: usually the loading time increases with the growth in the size of the model, but 1 hour is a lot, to me is usually ten minutes and i am currently working with a fully convolutional neural net that work on volumes, hard to check what could be the problem without code...

Comment: hi thank you very much for your reply ! 1 hour is really annoying when I want to change some small things then its the long wait, I also observe that the ```preparation``` is done in single thread, would there be any configuration/setting that I missed out lol that actually help with the speed of the initialization thank you very much

Comment: My model also requires nearly 1 hour. It takes a long time especially you do it on multiple GPUs. I guess 15M params are not that much. 1 hour is a bit long.

Comment: hi ,thank you very much for your reply ! 15M really is medium to small size nowadays, I believe the depth of layers matter more ```but so sadly I only have limited knowledge in tensorflow and c++ and coding in general :(``` I once a model with pure dense layer quite many more than 15M parameteres load in ~15mins , so 1 hour is the norm or ```even longer wait time``` if you decide to stack more layers into the model and not much can be done to help ?

Comment: Maybe a poor data loader? Try halving your training set size and see if the wait time changes.

Comment: I had the same problem because I forgot to convert the dataset from python list into numpy arrays. So every epoch 1 tf had to convert everything.